# Worklight 6.1 - Barcode Scanner Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I'm followed this IBM Worklight article instructions - 
[link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/WASFAQs/entry/using_a_barcode_scanner_with_worklight?lang=en).

On Eclipse - when I try to run *BarcodeScannerSampleBarcodeScannerSampleAppAndroid* - 
I get message box with title - `"Android Launch"`, that says:`"Your projects contains error".`

At Markers window I get this Error:

```
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 
'D:\Users\MyUser\workspaceNew\CaptureActivity\bin\captureactivity.jar'
BarcodeScannerSampleBarcodeScannerSampleAppAndroid
Build path
Build Path Problem
```

Directory - `"D:\Users\MyUser\workspaceNew\CaptureActivity\bin\"` doesn't contains `"captureactivity.jar"` file.

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: What answer do you expect apart from "fix the project configuration so that the library is found."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yaniv thanks.

The problem was in CaptureActivity library.
After importing *"Existing Android Code Into Workspace"*, I should **BUILD** the project library.
Then it create a directory - `"D:\Users\MyUser\workspaceNew\CaptureActivity\bin\"` with  `"captureactivity.jar"` file in it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow the instructions in the blog post to the letter.
It sounds like you did not follow the last step, which says to:

1. Right-click the generated Android project and select Properties
2. In the Android entry from the left pane, click on Add and select CaptureActivity

---

Fuller steps:

1. Download & extract the zip from GitHub: https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner/archive/master.zip
2. In Eclipse, File > Import > Android > Existing Android Code Into Workspace
3. Click on Browse and then find the extracted folder
4. Navigate in it into ../BarcodeScanner-master/src/android/LibraryProject and click Finish

Then you need to continue with creating the Worklight project. It's two different projects.

1. In your Worklight project, you need to navigate to your-project\apps\your-app\android\native
2. There you need to right-click on the src folder and select Import... > General > File System
3. Navigate to the same extracted folder, into ../BarcodeScanner-master/src/android and click Next
4. Tick the checkbox next to the android option that will appear after step 3

Next you need to configure AndroidManifest.xml and config.xml in the same location (your-app\android\native).

In both the CaptureActivity AndroidManifest.xml and the Worklight project AndroidManifest.xml I've set the minSdkVersion to 19, which I have installed.

Now,

1. Once you're done with that, build the project.
2. Right-click on the generated Android project > Properties > Android
3. Click the Add... button and select the CaptureActivity library

Make sure to **not select** the "Is library" checkbox.

Comment: Then supply your project. Either way the instructions in the blog post are valid.

Comment: Idan, thanks but I alreay did it. Maybe I should run CaptureActivity project before? When I try to, I get this message: **Android library projects cannot be launched**.

Comment: No, there is no reason to launch it. It's supposed to be included, not run separately. You are misconfiguring it. Start over.

Comment: Idan, I start over the project. I can't get this class - "You should be able see that the com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner.java file has been imported into the src folder". I get in in folders. com\phonegap... It should be the problem?

Comment: Updated the answer with fuller steps.

Comment: Idan, thanks again. still not works. when I bulid the BarcodeScannerSampleBarcodeScannerSampleAppAndroid generated proj without adding CaptureActivity library, it's building successfully but fail to run pludin - in javascript. When I add CaptureActivity library, exclamation mark appears on project icon, and at Markers window I get previous Error: **The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'D:\Users\MyUser\workspaceNew\CaptureActivity\bin\captureactivity.jar'**

Comment: Well, you're doing something wrong. Provide your Worklight Studio project. Upload it to dropbox.

Comment: here's the [project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3s_FnkA9LJXaktjLXVmRGFNZUk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I followed my steps with your project, and I was able to launch the app in the Android emulator.

Comment: Idan, please check my project without more steps. I already did the steps you wrote. I hope you can tell me what's the problem with my work. How can I solve "Java Build Path Problem"? it's looking after  'CaptureActivity\bin\captureactivity.jar'. Thanks!

Comment: The jar file is on your own filesystem, **of course** I must follow steps(!). I'm sorry, I don't know what you're doing there, but it's got nothing to do with Worklight. Just generic steps that I don't know why they are failing to you.

Comment: Hi Idan, I agree that the steps are generic and simple. But, still, it's not works... It's looking for this jar, that should be located in the plugin library. but it isn't there, and also library bin.  I can see the error also in BarcodeScannerSampleBarcodeScannerSampleAppAndroid Java Build Path  -> Libraries. Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed one step.

> ```
> - First we need to import the Java facade to the plugin. This is the code that implements the 
>   mandatory CordovaPlugin class and the exec() method. In the Worklight project, go to the 
>   location for the Java code
>   BarcodeScannerSample/apps/BarcodeScannerSampleApp/android/native/src 
> - Right-click on the src folder and select Import...> File System
> - Select the directory
>   <GIT CLONE FOLDER>/BarcodeScanner/src/android 
>   Select File > Import, of type File System, the contents of the com folder from the same 
>   source folder
>   <GIT CLONE FOLDER>/BarcodeScanner/src/android 
>   You should be able see that the com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner.java 
>   file has beenimported into the src folder.
> ```

And make sure you configured the config.xml and AndroidManifest.xml properly.

You can find the file here: https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner/

- Click on "Clone in Desktop".
- Extract the zip file.
- Import the resources as following.
  https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/WASFAQs/resource/BLOGS_UPLOADED_IMAGES/scan_importplugin.jpg