# How to integrate Phonegap BarCodeScanner Plugin to IBM worklight Project

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, phonegap-plugins

I need to create a BarcodeScanner App in IBM worklight using phonegap plugins. I just need to know how to add cordova plugins to IBM worklight project. What are the files that needs to be changed?

Plugin to be used - com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here for tutorials about how to create Cordova plug-ins for Worklight/MobileFirst Platform:

- [Adding native functionality to hybrid applications](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/adding-native-functionality/)

Then read various topics about the same subject:

- http://sajjad-hussainsh.blogspot.co.il/2013/05/ibm-worklight-phonegap-barcodescanner.html
- [Worklight 6.1 - Barcode Scanner Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633094/worklight-6-1-barcode-scanner-plugin)
- [IBM Worklight - How to add barcode scanner phonegap plugin into config.xml in Xcode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273980/ibm-worklight-how-to-add-barcode-scanner-phonegap-plugin-into-config-xml-in-xc)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992582/how-to-implement-barcode-reader-using-ibm-worklight/21993328#21993328