# How to implement Barcode scanner in iOS using ibm mobilefirst 7.0?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

how to implement Barcode scanner for iOS in hybrid application using ibm mobilefirst 7.0.

Comment: It starts with running a Google query and first attempting to implement. Then, come with questions.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a license to use manateeworks' barcode SDK, which also supports IBM MobileFirst,

Or attempt any of the following: [How to integrate Phonegap BarCodeScanner Plugin to IBM worklight Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855070/how-to-integrate-phonegap-barcodescanner-plugin-to-ibm-worklight-project)